# Representing multiple errors in Go

Tags: error-handling, go

The MediaWiki API may return multiple errors. Is this a idiomatic way of representing them?

```
type MediaWikiError struct {
    Code    string      `json:"code"`
    Data    interface{} `json:"data"`
    Message string      `json:"text"`
    Module  string      `json:"module"`
}

func (e *MediaWikiError) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("MediaWiki module \"%s\" reported an error: %s (%s)", e.Module, e.Message, e.Code)
}

type MediaWikiErrors []*MediaWikiError

func (e MediaWikiErrors) Error() string {
    switch len(e) {
    case 0:
        return ""
    case 1:
        return e[0].Error()
    default:
        codes := make([]string, len(e))
        for i, err := range e {
            codes[i] = err.Code
        }
        return fmt.Sprintf("MediaWiki API reported multiple errors: %s", strings.Join(codes, ", "))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1. Don't use \" in string

Go provide a very nice way to handle quote (`"`) in strings:

instead of

```
fmt.Sprintf("MediaWiki module \"%s\" reported an error: %s (%s)", ...)
```

you can use

```
fmt.Sprintf(`MediaWiki module "%s" reported an error: %s (%s)`, ...)
```

It's easier and nicer to read

#### 2. Use range loop instead of switch

Instead of specifiying behavior for 3 cases ( 0, 1, default), we can use a simple range loop

So this

```
func (e MediaWikiErrors) Error() string {
    switch len(e) {
    case 0:
        return ""
    case 1:
        return e[0].Error()
    default:
        codes := make([]string, len(e))
        for i, err := range e {
            codes[i] = err.Code
        }
        return fmt.Sprintf("MediaWiki API reported multiple errors: %s", strings.Join(codes, ", "))
    }
}
```

become simply this:

```
func (e MediaWikiErrors) Error() (errMsg string) {
    for _, err := range e {
        errMsg += err.Error() + "\n"
    }
    return errMsg
}
```

I prefer joining errors with a line return (`\n`) instead of a comma, but it's just my personal taste. Multiple errors would be printed like this:

```
MediaWiki module "module_1" reported an error: parsing error (3)
MediaWiki module "module_2" reported an error: access denied (22)
```

Comment: That are some useful suggestion, but it doesn't answer my question. Is it idiomatic to represent multiple errors in this way?

Comment: @R3turnz I guess it is. The MongoDB driver use something similar to handle bulk insert error for example. The best way to now is to look at how the standard library / project maintained by go authors handle similar problems

Comment: Do you have an example where the Go authors faced a similar problem?

Comment: @R3turnz maybe [golint source](https://github.com/golang/lint/blob/master/lint.go). It reads .go file, and then print all "style" error

Comment: In addition to your comment wrt using back-tick string literals you can also get rid of the quotes in the format string by replacing `"%s"` with `%q` which is more readable and handles issues such as as the string argument itself contains a character that needs quoting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is idiomatic. You have access to all relevant details of the individual errors, as well as you have implemented the `error` interface.

I don't think there should ever be an empty `MediawikiErrors` object, or at least its `Error` function should never be called, but for convenience returning an empty string there is fine.